# Sinatra: Why are my artists saving to all users and not just the currently logged in user?

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller, sinatra, crud

The artist objects save to @artists but no matter which user I log in as, i see the whole list

Models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users_artists
    has_many :artists, through: :users_artists
    has_many :artworks, through: :artists
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :artworks
    has_many :users_artists
    has_many :users, through: :users_artists
end

class UserArtists < ActiveRecord::Base 
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :artist
  end
```

Relevant code from my artists controller, and the paths seem to be functioning properly, the issue lies with the way artists are save

```
 get '/artists' do 
       if   !logged_in?
            redirect to '/login'
       else
            @artists = Artist.all
            erb :'artists/index'       
       end
    end

    get '/artists/new' do 
        if !logged_in?
            redirect '/login' 
        else
            @artist = Artist.new
            erb :'artists/new'
        end
    end

    post '/artists' do 
        if !logged_in?
              redirect to "/login"
            else
            @artist = current_user.artists.create(name: params[:name],notes: params[:notes])
            current_user.save  
                if
                  @artist.save
                  redirect "/artist/show"
                else 
                    redirect to "/artists/new"
                end
        end
    end
```

Migrations, i've changed the UsersArtists pluralization a few times and felt like i was getting closer.

```
class CreateArtists < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
      create_table :artists do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.text :notes
        t.integer :user_id
        t.timestamps null: false
      end
    end  
end

class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.text :email
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps null: false
  end
  end
end

class CreateUsersArtists < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :users_artists do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :artist_id
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of this:

```
@artists = Artist.all
```

This loads the full artist list, and that's what you're displaying.

Instead, filter it by the current user:

```
@artists = current_user.artists
```

Comment: thank you, however when I try that, I get the error NameError at /artists
uninitialized constant User::UsersArtist. I also tried changing the name of the userartist.rb model to, class UsersArtist. do you know why that is

Comment: Not exactly sure. Maybe go into rails console and check that `UsersArtist` is defined and that you can call `User.first.artists`. You may need to change the file name to match the class name, if you changed it.